# adding title id in Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to create a multidimensional to store Category name, titles under that category with the title ids to be used in view file. All my efforts are in vain. I could do something like below in my Model.How can I place project id along with each title

```
$categories[$rows['proj_category']][] = $rows['proj_item_title'];
```

I need to add proj_item_id in this array. Please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I had tried to create another field in the array within the array '$categories' But I could not get it right despite trying for a long time until I received the help here. I never seek out help unless I have tried everything I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add additional dimension to your array

```
$categories[$rows['proj_category']][] = array(
    'title'    => $rows['proj_item_title'],
    'item_id'  => $rows['proj_item_id '],
);
```

And its using should be something like below:

```
foreach($categories as $cats)
{
    foreach($cats as $product)
    {
        echo $product['title'];
        echo $product['item_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer was correct you can mark it as correct

Comment: Hi Hossein,  it would also work if I wrote foreach ($categories as $categories=>$cats) in the first foreach loop. Kindly share your idea. Why doesn't it make difference?

Comment: Yea your solution is correct and you can use it instead. If you use my method you are able to add more items if you need in future without changing structure

Comment: Yours is the best solution as it allows for more elements to be stored. I am going to stick to your logic only. thanks!